# how to save image into DB with attached element on it by drag&drop event and display the image with attached element with same position as it was drop

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

**image.jpg**
[view the image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mbps.jpg)

**index.php**

```
<!-- container div to display image-->
<div class="imageBox">
   <img src="img/img1.jpg" id="myImage" alt="simpleImage">
</div>

<!--container div for dragging and dropping element-->
<div class="drag-drop-container">
  <div id="draggable">
     <p>Ajax</p>
  </div>

  <div id="droppable">
     *********
  </div>
</div>

<button id="saveButton"></button>
```

NB: drag and drop container is placed on top of imageBox

**jquery.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#draggable").draggable({
     containment: "parent"  
         });
});
```

Comment: so you want to upload a image, give option to user for croping and save it?

Comment: No, the image is already displayed there and it is from the database,i needs a way of restoring back into a database when a user click button "save"

Comment: again upload this modified image into some folder and save the new image path to DB

Comment: @Atanu, thanx i've tried out and works fine